# Angular select box with 2 values

Tags: angularjs

I want to have a select box with a list of price range.

Example:

```
- 0 to $2,000
- $2,000 to $3,500
- $3,500 to $5,000
- $5,000 to $7,500
- $7,500 to $10,000
- $10,000
```

When the user select one option I want to set the budget range:
For instance if the user clicks on - $3,500 to $5,000 then is set the following values:

```
$scope.var.x = 3500;
$scope.var.y = 5000;
```

I would like to do this directly on a partial if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's something easy to do if you have correctly understood the Angular principles. I think that you have something like an array which contains your price ranges:

```js
$scope.ranges = [
    {start : 0, end : 2000},
    {start : 2000, end : 3500},
    {start : 3500, end : 5000},
    {start : 5000, end : Infinity}
];
```

Then, simply construct your `<select>` menu from this array:

```html
<select ng-model="selectedRange" ng-options="range as '$' + range.start + ' to $' + range.end for range in ranges"></select>
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88tTm/)</kbd>

Notice that if you have just a list of price…

```js
$scope.ranges = [0, 2000, 3500, 5000];
```

… it's not really difficult to reconstruct the first object I've shown.

Comment: +1 `(range.start | currency)` inside `ng-options` would also work.

Comment: Ok that I know how to do but how do i set $scope.x and $scope.y and is it possible to do it only from a partial?

Comment: because if not i have to play with the watch which i want to avoid, i think that a simple way to do this in angular is possible

Comment: I can't figure out what's the problem. Please, show us some code (or pseudo-code) that can illustrate what you want to do.

Comment: the users click on a select box with a selected range A to B, then $scope.x = A and $scope.y = B as a result. I cannot be more specific it seems pretty straightforward :/

Comment: Well, that's exactly what my code proposal is doing : the user clicks on a select box with a selected range A to B, then $scope.selectedRange.start = A and $scope.selectedRange.end = B…

Comment: if you can make it work without the object selectedRange between the scope and the start/end that's what i want

Comment: So $scope.start $scope.end

Comment: var wasn't supposed to be the range is another more complex object, that contains the range as well. Sorry if it was some sort of confusion because of this

Comment: Simply use the [ngChange](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChange) directive. [Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88tTm/1/).